# How do I auto fill the Input Table records for batch processing the Delete Field Tool, in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, batch, delete

I have over 500 individual shapefiles that need to have a specific field removed from their tables. In theory I can use the batch option with the Delete Field tool, but adding the Input Table cell for 500+ records is extraordinarily tedious. Is there some way to automate or semi-automate that part of the process? It hardly makes the batch aspect worth it as it seems to work right now.

Comment: How are you iterating? Is this python or model builder or just batch mode for a tool? In batch mode you should be able to select the cell you want, right click and then fill should be one of the options to fill the entire column with that value in every row.

Comment: You can drug and drop them from ArcCatalog.

Comment: I hope you mean *drag* and drop #FelixIP, your method sound like it could have legal implications.

Comment: Indeed! Although 1st spelling sounds better.

Comment: I feel a bit foolish in that I never thought drag-and-drop would work. Now that I know how this works, I'm draggin em in like a mo.. well like.. a lot. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for them in Explorer, e.g. "*.shp" (right window), select all and drag to tool window ( left one):

[image]

Use "fill" option on field column.

Comment: This was such a trivial answer, I had to laugh! It never occurred to me to drag-and-drop. Thanks for the answer!